# Is it possible to autoplay a video when using module media_youtube, and perform an action when the video ends?

Tags: media, files

I am using [media_youtube](https://drupal.org/project/media_youtube) module for embedded videos from youtube.
I am looking for a way to autoplay video as soon as it appears. Is it possible with this module?
Also I would like to make some action as soon as video ends. It would probably be going to some other drupal article. Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The module developers hid these options well!

1. Click on Configuration (or Structure depending on versions)
2. Click on File Types
3. For Video, click on manage file display
4. For the display you are using (Default, Link, Preview, etc..), click on the YouTube Video tab under Display Settings.
5. Check the box called "Autoplay video on load"

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much. What about some action afer video ending? I am pretty sure that one may achieve this with google youtube API (I have seen option to enable this in module's configuration), but I have no idea how to get to this API from drupal's site.

Comment: For those who are wondering, the option to "Show related videos when playback ends" is also there.  In my case I wanted to remove that ability and uploading the videos with `?rel=0` at the end was not working.  Unchecking that option did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

just want to add here that if you're using Safari and you have an extension such as ClicktoFlash installed and enabled it might be that your browser will automatically play the video depending on your settings of that extension. So if you have your video still 'autoplays' have a look there as well.